# Connect to database .net core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I'm trying to build an API using .net core, i create Entity "User", DbContext, Repository and a Controller to test if it works, but when i test it with Postman i receive always a 500 Http statu indicating an internel server error.
Here is my Entity:

```
public class User


      {
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public long Id { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string UserName { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string Password { get; set; }
            public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; } = new List<Post>();
        }
```

here is th DbContext:

```
 public class NetworkDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public NetworkDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }
```

here is the Repository :

```
 public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
    {
        private readonly NetworkDbContext _context;
        public UserRepository(NetworkDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public void AddUser(User user)
        {
            _context.Users.Add(user);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUsers()
        {
            return _context.Users.ToList();
        }

        public void RemoveUser(User user)
        {
            _context.Users.Remove(user);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Update(User user)
        {
            _context.Users.Update(user);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

The startup.cs :

```
 public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

            if (env.IsEnvironment("Development"))
            {
                // This will push telemetry data through Application Insights pipeline faster, allowing you to view results immediately.
                builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: true);
            }

            builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

            services.AddMvc();
            var connectionString = Configuration["connectionString"]; //connection string to sqlServer
            services.AddDbContext<NetworkDbContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
            services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

            app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

and finally here is my Controller :

```
 [Route("api/user")]
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private UserRepository _repository { get; set; }
        public UserController(UserRepository  repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public void AddUser([FromBody] User user)
        {
            if (user == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        _repository.AddUser(user);
        return CreatedAtRoute("GetUser", user);
        }

    }
```

In fact it indicates in the diagnostic tool an Exception : "System.InvalidOperationException", Unable to resolve service for type "SocilNetworkApi.Models.UserRepository".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not related to EF but it's the dependency of controller

Controller is depending on `UserRepository` so runtime tries to resolve that type but that's not mapped. That's why it gives you that error.

You need to make your controller dependent on `IUserRepository` not on `UserRepository`

```
[Route("api/user")]
public class UserController : Controller
{   
    private IUserRepository _repository { get; set; }
    public UserController(IUserRepository  repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
}
```

This should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

"SocilNetworkApi.Models.UserRepository" needs to be registered with the dependency injection container for it to be injected into the UserController constructor.

Comment: Sorry I missed that, I am on mobile.  You need to inject the interface not the concrete class.